# Why does my infix operator compile unless imported?

Tags: haskell

I have the following in a `module Util` that I use widely without issues:

```
(>~) = flip fmap
infix 8 >~

(>>~) :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m (t b)
(>>~) = Control.Monad.forM
infix 8 >>~
```

*(The explicit type sig is only because despite the bleedingly obvious "it's just an alias for a built-in func" GHC couldn't figure this out and forced me to, so let's ignore this here.)*

NOW, in another module (same project) I import the above operators and oddly enough, the following few lines **DO** compile just-fine:

```
listAllFiles rootdirpath reldirs modtimer =
    let allfiles = (dirpaths >>~ foreachdir) >~~ concat
        (>~~) = flip fmap
        infix 8 >~~
        ...
```

But the following variation (which I'd prefer obviously) will fail to compile:

```
listAllFiles rootdirpath reldirs modtimer =
    let allfiles = (dirpaths >>~ foreachdir) >~ concat
        ...
```

Isn't that odd, given how the *successful* `>~~` declared locally right above was defined in *exactly the very identical way* as the imported `>~`?

Where's the logic in that, can anyone share their insights on this? Oh, here's the error:

```
Files.hs:88:21: error:
* Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
  Expected type: [[[(FilePath, Data.Time.Clock.UTCTime)]]]
    Actual type: IO [[(FilePath, Data.Time.Clock.UTCTime)]]
* In the first argument of `(>~)', namely
    `(dirpaths >>~ foreachdir)'
  In the expression: (dirpaths >>~ foreachdir) >~ concat
  In an equation for `allfiles':
      allfiles = (dirpaths >>~ foreachdir) >~ concat
```

.. but obviously this question isn't about how to deal with *"Couldn't match type 'a' with 'b'"* errors per-se / in the general case --- keep in mind in a functional language I expect identical definitions to work identically, whether defined in a local `let` or in an imported module. What in the heck could be disrupting this general principle in this specific instance?

It's not a show-stopper, I could skip the fancy ops go `fmap concat (etc)` and just get on with business. But I guess there's maybe something deeper to learn here (or an obscure bug encountered to be reported)!

Comment: No idea, but I'd try adding an explicit type signature for `>~` as well in you module `Util`

Comment: This sounds like the monomorphism restriction - which @chi's suggestion would address.  And that's also why `>>~` needed a type signature.  And for what it's worth, only primitive functions are built-in.  Certainly nothing in `Control.Monad` is primitive.

Comment: *"The explicit type sig is only because despite the bleedingly obvious "it's just an alias for a built-in func" GHC couldn't figure this out and forced me to, so let's ignore this here."* No. Don't ignore. That's exactly the source for your error. Never write pointfree bindings without a type signature if you want to export them. Even better, never export any function without a type signature, their behavior might break (silently) on a library update.

Comment: For simple `my_alias_name = defined_elsewhere` no-special-annotations usage, not sure I'll ever grasp why the issue even comes up. In each & every such instance, right after the successful parse and first round of processing, `my_alias_name` shouldn't even *exist* as its own identity anymore and be replaced throughout by the thing it pointed to, no? Why keep such useless pointers even around, they only existed (indeed, given their *id* nature only possibly *could* exist) for readability/swappability.. This then wouldn't even necessitate type inference since the original definition is taken.

Comment: @chi tried (just used what *ghci* gave me on `:t (flip fmap)`) and other code that previously compiled (and worked) now demanded type sigs too apparently or in any event type-errored-out. Well I tend to wait with my sigs until a project is "done", so in the very few cases where `>~` won't work (usually in combination with `>>~`) I'll just go with `<$>` instead.